# Does Healthkit Sync?

Tags: ios, health.app, health-kit

Does Healthkit sync between devices? For example, if I have IOS 8.02 installed on  iPhones 4S and 5S, should I expect that data on the 5S Health Dashboard will appear on the 4S Health Dashboard?

Answer (score 6):

On iOS 8.0.x the health app does no syncing of any health kit data or configuration.

You only get the app on iPhone and iPod builds and there is no cloud component of the data. It resides on each device and only gets backed up to iCloud as a device backup and not synced like other things can in iCloud such as calendar and contacts data.

Comment: That's so annoying!